# How to get data after installing the Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have installed the Facebook SDK into Android app. The thing is that I need certain data when the user installs the app via Facebook. The data I need is the Ad Group, Keywords (if possible) and campaign name/id. I can't seem to figure out how to get it. I've checked the SDK documentation and Ads-Helper tools as well as the Ads-SDK documentation.

I was expecting the SDK to give me the data when launching the app for the first time, but I can't seem to find documentation about it.

How can I get ad data in the app when launched? Can I get that from the Facebook SDK?

Comment: You need to make the appropriate API calls, to request the data you are interested in.

Comment: But what API calls from Facebook SDK?

Comment: Go read the API documentation, and find out. It’s not our responsibility here to do that for you.

Comment: I have read Facebook SDK API documentation and did not found. Thats why i asking for help.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/v7.0 gives you an overview, which fields/edges are available on what type of object.

Comment: This is Graph Facebook API is for backend side. But i am asking for Facebook SDK Android part. So when my app will be installed from facebook ads and in my app i want to know - from witch adset it was installed

Comment: Then https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/ should be what you need to look at, I think.